# Populate a subdocument with promises into an instance method

Tags: mongoose

I need to populate sub document into an instance method, and i made it work with callbacks after testing different patterns. But i would like to know how to use promises in this case, and if there is a reason if we cannot (maybe i should not meet this need).

The populate() method returns the original document (with any changes)...

Here is what i wanted to do:

```
MyModel.methods.myMethod = function () {
    return this.populate({ model: 'User', path: 'rank.user'})
      .then(function() { // TypeError: promise.then is not a function
        // Expected to be able to do things here...
      });   
};
```

And this works:

```
MyModel.methods.myMethod = function () {
    return this.populate({ model: 'User', path: 'rank.user'}, function(err, populatedDucument) {
       // Works fine...
     });    
};
```

Any idea how to populate with promises here ?
I am using the v4.1.0 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`execPopulate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-execPopulate) on a model instance [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) call without a callback to execute the population and return a promise.

```js
MyModel.methods.myMethod = function () {
    return this.populate({ model: 'User', path: 'rank.user'})
      .execPopulate()
      .then(function() {
        // ...
      });   
};
```

Comment: Works fine ! I didn't notice this method in the doc, thanks !